# Create separate landing page on blogger

Tags: blogger

thanks for viewing this post and I know this not a **programming** related question. Well I have created a site [My Blog](https://my-p-journey.blogspot.com/) and as you could see there are several links on the home page like

```
C#--|-> Beginner
    |-> Advanced
    |-> Tips
```

C# (Parent node and Beginner,Advanced etc are child nodes or menus).

Now what I want,
when someone click on the link C# it should redirect to a custom landing page
(custom means I don't want to show any comment section at the bottom of the page)

There is an option to create a page from the scratch just like this but after creating it renders like this
[image].

So my requirement is I want to create a page from scratch using my own html where header and footer will be same but its should not display any comment section like this..[a new page](https://my-p-journey.blogspot.com/p/hello-world_24.html)

Help needed :)

posted [here](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/4722335?hl=en) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code after body tag

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>
    <style>
     .post-footer,
     .plasma-post-author,
     .comments {  
         display: none !important;
     }
     </style> 
</b:if>
```

Comment: I am quite new about this but I think every page I am creating is considered as static right?  blog.pageType == "static_page" . What if I want to show comments on a specific page?? @umusi

Comment: change 'static_page' by your page URL. source [https://ultimatebloggerguide.blogspot.com/2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html]

Comment: and change  display: none !important; by display: initial !important;

Answer (score 0):

You can disable comments on blogger page from the bottom left of page editor

Go to Page Editor > Page settings > Options > Reader comments

To disable share buttons, you need to edit post footer code in blog posts widget.